# How do I prefetch url's in ionic/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, ionic-framework

I am pretty new to ionic 1 and I am working on an application (with Ionic 1 and angular js)  with multiple URLs where each URL brings up a list of categories, followed by a list of items for each category and each item has a document URL. How do I preload all these URLs on launch in the background but not display them?Is there any way this can be achieved? a good code sample or tutorial will help greatly.
Also, please let me know if this will be the best approach, as in pre-loading and pre-caching all content upon launch or should it be done category by category or some other way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about angulars $templateCache service ? Docs here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: isn't that for already loaded pages? Is there a way I can get all the url's and their content as in prefetch or preload them before and cache them aswell before going to the actual page?

Comment: Do all the items have single view (template) to display the single item details? If so then what do you mean by "pre-load url and not display them"?

Comment: theres multiple views in my app. With the click of each category, it takes you to a sub category, which in turn has a list of items, clicking on each opens a document url. You can find the code for the app.js file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638667/how-do-i-pre-cache-url-content-in-ionic-1-angular-1. I am retrieving the document url's there, is it possible to pre fetch and pre load before hand ,so i can cache the entire content even when the network goes off

Comment: Have you tried using local storage or local DB?

Comment: Here are the ones for Ionic 1 lifecycle-events  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/order-of-lifecycle-events/28251/2

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple Asynchronous service calls in background using `$q.`
Make a list of URL's in an array and call them at once using `$q.all(listOfURL).`
Using promises retrieve each response.

By making this asynchronous you can save lot of time.

After getting response you can either store them in `$rootScope` or in `localStorage/sessionStorage.`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't want to load data in next screens, deliver user flawless experience.

Yes you can start loading URLs on you very first page as you want them to get the data you want to use in future screens.

In terms of **storage**

> 1. In AngularJs if you want something to persist throughout the application scope you should use $rootscope[beware keeping lot of data
>      may leads to memory issues, you need to clear it regularly].
> 2. Or another option is to store it in Localstorage. And fetch as per your need.
> 3. If you want you can share those arrays between different controllers of screens.

**While loading[response getting from server]** you can do two things 

`1. get single JSON response having all the data 
2.have multiple urls, and load them serially.`

As per your requirement of loading 5th (page)screen data in advance it's not good practice, and even stop user from seeing updates but as it's your requirement. We've couple of approaches:

1. Add all the category and their respective details as per your pastebin like cardiac then it's details.. kidney then details..
   You can do this with managing hierarchies [categories] like parent main group and it's child sub group in JSONArray and details in JSONObject. (This change would be on sender side -server)

You need to load only one url to get all data.
So you don't need to load with different urls like now your doing. But beware this would be a big Json. So when you store it separate the categories and required data [screen-wise requirements] and store in local storage so easy for access.

2. Another approach would be you have to provide your [category] subgroup names to load so the loading would be like firing same URL with different category names to get data and store it in local storage.

This may lead to fire around 10-15[depends on your categories] urls may affect the UI thread response.
This won't need any changes on your server side response.

**

> Programmatically approach to load urls sequentially:

**

> URL Loading: This method will get detail of particular category [id or anything
>   works for you]. This will fire a http request and return a result.

```
getCategoryDetails(category){
url = url+category;
return $http({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: url, 
        headers: --
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {  //<--- `.then` transforms the promise here
```

//You can ether store in local storage
            return response
        }, function onError(response) {
            throw customExceptionHadnler.getErrorMsg(response.status, response.data);
        });
    }

> Parallel : This method will do it in parallel, we just load categories[ids] as we have all of them and then use $q.all to wait for all the urls loading to finish.

```
 function loadUrlsParallel(urls) {
     var loadUrls = []
     for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
         loadUrls.push(getCategoryDetails(urls[i]))
     }
     return $q.all(loadUrls) 
}
```

> First API: This method to load first url and then Loading urls in
>   parallel call above method

```
getListOfCategories(){
url = url;
return $http({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: url, 
        headers: --
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {  //<--- `.then` transforms the promise here
```

//You can ether store in local storage or directly send response 
            return response
        }, function onError(response) {
            throw customExceptionHadnler.getErrorMsg(response.status, response.data);
        });
    }

> urls : you have to prepare list of urls with appending category to
>   load after loading first url[expecting this returns you all the
>   categories you will require in your app beforehand] and pass to
>   loadUrlsParallel method.
>
> You can write loadUrl methods as per your convenience, here whatever
>   is given is foe example purpose so may not run as it is.

You can load API responses every where from local storage where you've stored after API calls, So this will not ask you to execute API calls on every laoding of pages[screen]

Hope this helps you and solves your prob.

Comment: I actually want to pre-fetch content in URL's including next screens in angularjs. Is there a way to do this? Any detailed example /tutorial would be helpful

Comment: If you look at the approach closely, you've understood the way. You just need to use HTTP requests to get all the data from APIs and then refer storage methods to accomplish your purpose. I can't share code, but you can look for all 2 or 3 aspect separately, sure you will get good links.

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful for this. Any good examples would help

Comment: @MobileEvangelist has the right approach. create a service that your controller calls. Your service can call http requests to get your data and store it locally in a database or something similar.

Comment: I already do that. Please check pastebin.com/4MyqyAfp Not sure how I can retrieve all the possible url's and their content upon load as my app has multiple pages with navigation and the document url I am trying to retrieve is on the 5th page, accessible only after u click on a couple of categories to get there.

Comment: @MarissaNicholas Please check I've update the answer, hope this lead you in good direction.

Comment: Can you explain the second approach programatically with respect to my code.Didnt get it. First approach is not possible as i cannot change anything on server side and it will be a process to request it etc.

Comment: @MarissaNicholas According to your pastebin :
Hi could you please explain what will you pass to this as srcUrl:
getdetailData(srcUrl);
If this requires your categories as extra param like kidney, heart or anything that you want to load ... then call this methods right after your first get data[In this you must have all categories that you want to load on coming pages]. So now you will call this detail API in advance to get the details for all the available categories, As I guess. (I'm referring Category as something that you will pass to API on click of item.)

Comment: right now I am getting data page by page. I want to get entire content with urls right on app launch, the code for my app.js file is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638667/how-do-i-pre-cache-url-content-in-ionic-1-angular-1?noredirect=1#comment76408797_44638667

Comment: @Marissa Nicholas I've seen your another question. If you followed above mentioned method to load all urls[first get list of items then load all url with passing each item[id/category] from list and store in Localstorage] right one after another and storing it in local storage and then showing your content. This approach should not have any prob. Still not clear contact on email jayeshkvarma@gmail.com

Comment: can you explain programmatically how i can load all url's from the list in the beginning based on my code

Comment: @MarissaNicholas I've updated my answer to explain the approach programmatically, complete working example would not be possible to share. I guess you can pick up from here and find your way.

Comment: thanks for the effort, +50 for you before it expires. Also, I will try out your approach today and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Also, can you explain further on "Programmatically approach to load urls sequentially:" this is my services code: https://pastebin.com/4MyqyAfp . controller code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638667/how-do-i-pre-cache-url-content-in-ionic-1-angular-1 .

Comment: do i load it in ready function in app.js? or in services somewhere?

Comment: @MarissaNicholas You can write the code in service but if you want this to be done right after loading should start this in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - As the OP is already aware of and using localStorage, thus additional suggestions :-

In that case, you could either call all of your service methods for fetching data at startup or you could use a headless browser such as '**PhantomJS**' to visit these URLs at startup and fetch the data.

Thus, your code would look something like :-

```
var webPage = require('webpage');

var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://www.google.com/', function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
  // Do other things here...
});
```

For more information, regarding PhantomJS, please refer to the following links :-

http://phantomjs.org/
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html

**Earlier Suggestions**

Make an HTTP request in your service to fetch the data and store it to localStorage, as is shown below :-

```
$http.get('url', function(response) {
var obj = response.data;
window.localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(obj)); // Store data to localStorage for later use
});
```

For fetching data :-

```
var cachedData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('key')); // Load cached data stored earlier
```

Please refer to the following link for detailed information regarding '**localStorage**' :-
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please check my services code here : https://pastebin.com/4MyqyAfp I have already implemented the localstorage cache at individual level. But I would like to implement it such that i prefetch all the url's in the app right when the app launches and then i can load them even if the user is offline. Can you look at my code and suggest how I can modify it to achieve my criteria? Also, you can check my app.js code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638667/how-do-i-pre-cache-url-content-in-ionic-1-angular-1?noredirect=1#comment76408797_44638667

Answer (score 0):

Best way to share data between different views in angular is to use a service as it is a singleton and can be used in other controllers.
In your main controller you can prefetch your lists of categories asynchronously through a service which can be shared for next views.Below is a small demo which you refer

```
angular.module("test").service("testservice",function('$http',$q){
    var lists = undefined;
    // fetch all lists in deferred technique
    this.getLists = function() {
      // if lists object is not defined then start the new process for fetch it
      if (!lists) {
        // create deferred object using $q
        var deferred = $q.defer();
         // get lists form backend
        $http.get(URL)
          .then(function(result) {
            // save fetched posts to the local variable
            lists = result.data;
            // resolve the deferred
            deferred.resolve(lists);
          }, function(error) {
            //handle error
            deferred.reject(error);
          });
        // set the posts object to be a promise until result comeback
        lists = deferred.promise;
      }

      // in any way wrap the lists object with $q.when which means:
      // local posts object could be:
      // a promise
      // a real lists data
      // both cases will be handled as promise because $q.when on real data will resolve it immediately
      return $q.when(lists);
    };
this.getLists2=function(){
//do it similarly as above
};
}).controller("mainController",function(testservice,$scope){
    $scope.lists1=testervice.getLists()
        .then(function(lists) {
        //do something 
        });
    };
    $scope.lists2=testervice.getLists2()
        .then(function(lists) {
        //do something 
        });
    };
    $scope.lists1();
    $scope.lists2();
}).controller("demoController1",function(testservice,$scope){
    $scope.lists1=testervice.getLists()
        .then(function(lists) {
        //do something 
        });
    };
    $scope.lists2=testervice.getLists2()
        .then(function(lists) {
        //do something 
        });
    };
    $scope.lists1();
    $scope.lists2();
});
```

Comment: theres multiple views in my app. With the click of each category, it takes you to a sub category, which in turn has a list of items, clicking on each opens a document url. You can find the code for the app.js file here: stackoverflow.com/questions/44638667/…. I am retrieving the document url's there, is it possible to pre fetch and pre load before hand ,so i can cache the entire content even when the network goes off – Also, I have put the controllers together here: https://pastebin.com/3NYqrurz Please let me know based on my code what would be ideal